# d3 - stacked bar chart, bars not displaying

Tags: d3.js

I have a stackbiltz here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-at-stacked-bar-chart-2vngrr?file=index.js

Sorry this is vague, I don't know why this chart isn't working.

The console.log seem to doing the right things with the data but I'm obviously missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data bound to the `layers` should be the computed `stackedSeries` and not the original data. That's what's missing.

```
var layersBar = chart.selectAll('.layer')
.data(stackedSeries)
```

Fork: https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-at-stacked-bar-chart-qnfgwg?file=index.js